# Tmux select an appropriate window from the list

Tags: linux, tmux

I can navigate through windows by clicking `prefix + window number`, but when there are really large number of them it gets very inconvenient. I'd like to have a ability to navigate through them by selecting an appropriate one from the list. I mean something like this:

[image]

How to show such a window-selection list dialog?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Ctrl b, w` will list all windows.   To rebind it, you may put these lines to your `.tmux.conf`

```
# -n means it doesn't require ctrl+b as prefix.  
bind-key -n F2 next-window #f2 goes to next window. 
bind-key -n F1 previous-window
bind-key -n f3 choose-window #f3 displays window list.
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But how can I rebind it? What command does this?

Comment: @St.Antario see updated answer.